# Replace fullpage image background with video (HTML5)

Tags: css, html, html5-video

What is the easiest way to replace a full-page image background, with a video?

```css
video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url('#.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}
```

```html
<video poster="#.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="#.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I use the Spectral template by HTML5 UP, but can't figure out how to replace the banner background with a video, in the easiest and most efficient way. (https://html5up.net/spectral)

Thank you very much in advance :-)

Comment: There are too many answers to this. "Easiest" is something of a matter of opinion. Instead, please share what technique(s) you've tried and what problems you've had.

Answer (score 0):

In the header you can delete or replace the header background color, in the CSS --> #header

If that's what you mean.

```
-moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
-ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
//background: #2e3842; //delete or change this one
height: 3em;
left: 0;
line-height: 3em;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
```